# Bulk API v2 Failed because of wrong Data type

Tags: rest-api, data-loader, bulk-api

We are uploading vast amount of Data using the Bulk API v2 of Salesforce.
Some of our data do not match the valid data type of our fields in Salesforce resulting in a fail import of our data .

For example if we have a filled Phone_number that accepts only integers, if the record is 056999098e it will fail all the import and no record will be saved in Salesforce.
We had a similar example with an email record that was not formatted correctly and the result it failed ALL the import no record was saved into Salesforce

Is there a way to fail only the specific records and not ALL the import?
Using Dataloader is it the case we get a response of the successes and the errors.. success are imported .. errors are not

I need the same but using the API

thx you for your help ;)

Comment: From the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/creating_bulk_requests.htm): _Retrieve the results of the completed job by checking the successful results, failed results, and unprocessed records_

Comment: Hi,are you saying that the successful records are not getting updated because of some failed records.But,in Bulk load even if some records failed it will not stop saving the successful records to the database.Please check the doc to handle the failed records:https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_batches_failed_records.htm